# Jagged Array Sorting w/ Primary,Secondary,Tertiary Criterion

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting, multidimensional-array

Disclaimer: My background as a programmer is limitted to 1 university course in C++, and hobbyist vb.net macro programming.

My goal is to be able to take a bunch of data from a BOM, sort it conditionally, and then return a simple list with the document names.

I've come across some good information on LINQ and iComparable for structures/strings but could use some further guidance in what I need to do to make this happen.

Essentially it will be a multi level sort with some logic like:

```
-> Put objects with 'Drawing' = True first.
-> Sort then by ComponentDefinition/Secondary document desciber;
    (ie; assemblies and weldments, then plate, then structural steel, then hardware).
   -> Sort Assemblies and weldments by Renamed vs Matl'l Spec then by weight
    -> Sort Structural by type, then by size
    -> Sort hardware by nomial size, then by type, then by thread unc/unf, then by length
    -> Put the remainder last (ie; virtual components.
```

From what I've read, it seems like I can accomplish this by multiple sets of linq's if I can get it working,

Or I can use a Compare function and just compare each line in its entirety to the next (as my understand of it would suggest?)

So at the end of the day, I would want a list to spit out something like:

```
1) Drawing - Weldment - Named - Weight
2) Drawing - Assembly - Named - Weight
3) Drawing - Assembly - Unnamed - Weight
4) Drawing - Weldment - unnamed - weight
5) Drawing - Plate - 1" Thick x 48 sq in.
6) Drawing - Plate - 1" Thick x 36 sq in.
7) No Drawing - Plate - 1" Thick X 52 in
8) No Drawing - Plate - 1/2" thick X 52 in
9) No Drawing - 1/2" Bolt - UNC - 3"
10) No Drawing - 1/2" Bolt - UNC - 2"
11) No Drawing - 1/2" Nut - UNC
12) No Drawing - 1/2" Washer
13) No Drawing - 1/4" Bolt - UNC - 2"
14) No Drawing - Virtual Component
```

By using the Case 0 as the next level, and making a tree sort seems like the right way to do it, as long as I can get the basic tree working.
That way, I'm only sorting items based on how they ended up in the previous sort. (No need to go any further if I'm comparing an assembly to hardware as would be the secondary level of my sort after the Drawing/NoDrawing sort)

This is as far as I have gotten, and If I can figure out how to get this working, I'm thinking I'm likely set to go on from here

```
'Jagged Array Sorting with Tag Array
Sub Main()

Dim oBOMRowCount As Integer = 4

Dim oBOMFactorArray As Double(oBOMRowCount-1)(){}
    oBOMFactorArray(0) = {"2", "5"}
    oBOMFactorArray(1) = {"1", "5"}
    oBOMFactorArray(2) = {"1", "2"}
    oBOMFactorArray(3) = {"2", "7"}

Dim tagArray() As Integer = {0, 1, 2, 3}

' Initialize the comparer and sort
Dim myComparer As New RectangularComparer(oBOMFactorArray)
Array.Sort(tagArray, myComparer)

Dim i As Integer
For j = 0 To 3
    oLine = ""
    For i = 0 To 1
        If oLine = ""
            oLine = "oList[" & (oBOMFactorArray(j)(i)) & "]"
        Else
            oLine = oLine & "[" & (oBOMFactorArray(j)(i)) & "]"
        End If
    Next
    oStr = oStr & vbLf & oLine
Next
MsgBox(oStr)

End Sub()

Class RectangularComparer
Implements IComparer
' maintain a reference to the 2-dimensional array being sorted

Private sortArray(,) As Integer

' constructor initializes the sortArray reference
Public Sub New(ByVal theArray(,) As Double)
    sortArray = theArray
End Sub

Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
    ' x and y are integer row numbers into the sortArray
    Dim i1 As Integer = DirectCast(x, Integer)
    Dim i2 As Integer = DirectCast(y, Integer)

    Select Case sortArray(i1, 0).CompareTo(sortArray(i2, 0))
        Case -1
        Case 1
        Case 0
                Return sortArray(i1, 1).CompareTo(sortArray(i2, 1))
    End Select
    ' compare the items in the sortArray
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  You declare `oBOMFactorArray` as Double. then proceed to put strings in it:  `oBOMFactorArray(0) = {"2", "5"}`

Comment: I recommend using generics for your data structure `List(Of ... , Dictionary (Of ...)` instead of arrays since they are much easier to handle. Additionally writing own Comparer implementations can be useful, but here also: use generic version of `IComparer(Of Integer)`

Comment: My plan was to actually go through the information as I initially put it into the array, do an initial integer ranking; ie Drawing = 0, No Drawing = 1, and then run a simple integer comparison.

Is it also actually valid to do the tertiary comparisons within the Compare like that?

Comment: what do you mean by tertiary comparisons?

Comment: That there is a 3rd compare criterion in case the 2nd comparison (as well as the first) return equal. From some other forums I've been looking for help on, it appears it's just valid to nest these additional comparisons within the Compare Function, and that using Properties to get the various fields to compare is the best route to go.